# 1970-ish: Is it an accepted word? If so, what does it mean?

Tags: adjectives

*Modish*, *youngish*, *girlish* are accepted words. Is *1970-ish* accepted too, or even understood to be an English word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acceptable or not depends on where you try to use it. New words are formed like this all the time, but in a more formal situation you would only use such words if they are already widely known.

The meaning of *1970-ish* would depend on the situation. It can mean *circa 1970*:

> They stopped manufacturing that model 1970-ish.

It can also mean *in a 1970 style*:

> That lamp really looks 1970-ish.

Comment: I guess the first meaning is similar to the meaning of _hourish_, while the second meaning is someway similar to _girlish_.

Answer (score 1):

Accepted? Don’t know. I would print it. What it means: I’d expect either “circa 1970” or “in roughly the mode of the early 70s,” depending on usage context.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure a few purists might object, but I would suggest that it will be *accepted* by the majority, in that they will be fairly clear in what is meant by the term.

Thinking about it further, I'm not beyond tagging -ish onto various other words or phrases myself. Hardly the heights of eloquence but it usually gets the message across, which is surely purpose of language.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking in more general terms, when I append *ish* to a word, I'm usualy trying to convey the fact that I'm approximating.

So in your example, *1970-ish* would mean around the period of the year 1970 and the listener would realise that I could be talking about any of the several years before or after 1970, but that I don't know which one in particular.

But it depends on the context in which you use it.

Answer (score 0):

OED 2nd Ed supports -ish forming in your case.

> 2.2 Added to other ns., with the sense ‘Of or belonging to a person or thing, of the nature or character of’. These were not numerous in OE., whence only a few have come down to later times. Examples are folcisc popular, hǽðenisc heathenish, þéodisc national, inlęndisc inlandish, utlęndisc outlandish (which come close to the gentile group in 1); also męnnisc human, cildisc childish, cierlisc churlish. In later times this ending has become exceedingly common, sometimes in the earlier colourless sense as boyish, girlish, waggish, but chiefly in a derogatory sense, ‘Having the (bad or objectionable) qualities of’: as in apish, babyish, boarish, boorish, brutish, clownish, currish, devilish, doggish, doltish, dronish, foolish, foppish, goatish, ghoulish, hoggish, impish, knavish, mannish, monkish, mulish, owlish, prudish, roguish, selfish, shrewish, sluggish, sluttish, sottish, swinish, thievish, waspish, whorish, wolvish, womanish. (These have usually corresponding Ger. forms in -isch.) Also from names of things, with sense ‘of the nature of, tending to’, as in aguish, blockish, bookish, brinish, feverish, freakish, hellish, moorish; or from other parts of speech, as snappish, stand-offish, uppish.
>   In recent colloquial and journalistic use, -ish has become the favourite ending for forming adjs. for the nonce (esp. of a slighting or depreciatory nature) on proper names of persons, places, or things, and even on phrases, e.g. Disraelitish, Heine-ish, Mark Twainish, Micawberish, Miss Martineauish, Queen Annish, Spectator-ish, Tupperish, West Endish; all-over-ish, at-homeish, devil-may-care-ish, how-d'ye-doish, jolly-good-fellowish, merry-go-roundish, out-of-townish, and the like.

In the sentence :

> He is a 1970-ish.

I would understand his character is back to 1970s.

Comment: Which case reported here suits for _1970-ish_?